# ModuleNotFoundError Python

Tags: python, module

I have two files named dqd.py (with a class DQD) and main.py (which uses the class DQD). They are in the same folder so I wrote at the beginning of main.py:

`from dqd import DQD`

Yesterday, everything was fine when I ran main.py, but today it results in the error :
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dqd'`

Since yesterday, I haven't changed my files nor their path... I have downloaded Qutip and ffmpeg but I don't know why it would have changed anything.

If you have any idea I'd be grateful, thanks!

Comment: `from .dqd import DQD`

Comment: I already tried and get:

Comment: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: are you runing the script from same folder if yes then try to do `python -i main.py` then `import dqd` or `from dqd import DQD`

Comment: Yes both scripts are in the same folder... And ```python -i main.py``` returns an invalid syntax error...